# How does an Elementalist's "Swirling Winds" function?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The Elementalist has a skill [Swirling Winds](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Swirling_Winds) as Scepter's #4 skill in Air Attunement. Visually, it creates a 400 unit radius graphic of swirling winds around the character. Per the skill's description:

> **Swirling Winds**
>
> Create a swirling wind that destroys projectiles.

How exactly does the projectile destruction work?

- Is it only enemy projectiles?
- Do the projectiles need to start outside of the winds to be destroyed or does it destroy projectiles that start inside the winds, too?
- Would it destroy projectiles shot from the inside of the winds to the outside of them?
- Is there a distance limit (eg. would it destroy point-blank projectiles)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's define what a projectile is ([link](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Projectile)) :

> A projectile is a ranged attack which must travel from the user to the target before dealing damage.

To answer all your questions point by point, [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/16t7rb/elementalist_a_guide_to_the_focus/) was the best reference I could find.

**Is it only enemy projectiles?**

Yes.

**Do the projectiles need to start outside of the winds to be destroyed or does it destroy projectiles that start inside the winds, too?**

> where projectile cannot enter (or be created), as they are "destroyed".

No. If they shot from outside or directly from inside the area, it's the same.

**Would it destroy projectiles shot from the inside of the winds to the outside of them?**

Same question as above, so it's the same answer.

**Is there a distance limit (eg. would it destroy point-blank projectiles)?**

I don't understand this question.

Comment: I believe that OP wants to know if the spell will have any effect if the projectile is spawned "in his\her face", such as the enemy standing almost inside of OP's char. Tho, I think the answer will be "no". The effect usually is a whole 400 unit dome that surrounds the caster, so that anyone within that dome, including the caster, will be safe from projectiles.

Comment: The distance limit was essentially asking if the projectile created by a target inside the winds never gets created, or if it's created, travels a few units, and then gets destroyed. So, an enemy within a certain amount of units would still hit you.

Comment: Ok, now i get it, (you could combine questions 2, 3 and 4 but ok).
Well based on the reddit guide, non-allies projectiles can't be "created" inside the zone, so the distance won't change anything.

Comment: @Shunwoo By the way, the reddit post that you linked is a fantastic guide on the Focus. Thank you for finding that!